# iOS: SWRevealViewController and multiple NavigationControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm new to `iOS` development and i was looking for a side-menu technique to use in my application (something similar to `NavigationDrawer` in android) after i did my researches i was very impressed by the `SWRevealViewController` controller, but i have encountered this problem:

**Subject:** SWRevealViewController

**Problem:** I want when a user clicks on a cell (in the side-menu table view) to segue to another view scene and let this scene to be able to reveal the side menu as well (exactly like the original view scene).

**Possible:** Do i have to create another root view and make two custom segues, one linked with another side-menu and the other one linked to another navigation controller like i did with original view scene? *(which is very lame solution)*

**Reference:** Please see the image below

**My Question:** What should be instead of the question marked view scene in the image below?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should not be a segue from your sidebar controller to any other viewcontroller. instead in your sidebar controllers `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you should create the targetviewcontroller (depending on the indexpath) and then show it using

```
self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:targetViewController animated:YES;
```

feel free to ask if anything is unclear. :)

Comment: Can the `targetViewController` be a tableViewController ?

Comment: it can be every kind of viewcontroller. often it is a viewcontroller embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: yes but it's not taking my tableViewController class, i think it can only accept `UIViewController` , right ?

Comment: then you are doing something wrong. it should be a problem! wanna show me your project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77099/discussion-between-fadi-obaji-and-andre-slotta).